# Tuning Nginx/CentOS for server lots of static content

Tags: nginx, centos, performance, iostat

I have a linux machine 64bit (centos5.5), 2.83GHz Q9550, 6gb ram and a single SATA 500gb drive.

From this machine I only serve thumbnails, most around 10kb in size and at this point there are about 7 million thumbnails on the server. I have them setup in a /25/25/25/25 folder setup which was recommended to me.

On average the nginx status report shows that im serving about 300 to 400 active connections.

EXAMPLE:

```
Active connections: 297 
server accepts handled requests
 1975808 1975808 3457352 
Reading: 39 Writing: 8 Waiting: 250
```

Now the problem is that this machine is having a very hard time, and is getting slower as my site is gettin busier. The load is always around 8 to 9.

I noticed iostat showing over 100% util.

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.20     1.40 99.80 31.14  1221.56   255.49    11.28   114.14  831.81   7.62  99.84

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.20     0.60 100.80 24.00  1192.00   203.20    11.18   113.77  775.42   8.02 100.04

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.20   314.80 44.80 130.00   598.40  3547.20    23.72   113.76  937.18   5.72 100.02

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     5.40 56.20 110.80   660.80   937.60     9.57   112.37  518.01   5.99 100.04

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.60    12.40 82.80 41.60  1008.00   432.00    11.58   113.66  852.51   8.04 100.04
```

Below you can see some of my nginx config settings:

```
worker_processes  6;
worker_connections  4096;

http {
        include                 mime.types;
        default_type            application/octet-stream;
        #access_log             logs/access.log  main;
        sendfile                on;
        #tcp_nopush             on;
        keepalive_timeout       4;
        gzip                    on;
        gzip_http_version       1.1;
        gzip_vary               on;
        gzip_comp_level         2;
        gzip_proxied            any;
        gzip_types              text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_buffers            16 8k;
}
```

My question is, apart from moving to RAID setups, and possibly SSD's, is there anything that I can tweak/tune to get more out of this machine? I have a feeling a server like mine should be able to handle much more than about 300 to 400 active nginx connections per second.

Comment: this would be much better put at http://serverfault.com

Comment: One thing you should probably just do asap is to disable atime , mount your filesystem where the files reside on with the `noatime` option - this will reduce drive IO quite a bit - you likely don't need the access time of files to be updated

Comment: Thanks for the reply, teh noatime seems a great option. I found this tutorial, http://www.howtoforge.com/reducing-disk-io-by-mounting-partitions-with-noatime and I would have to add the noatime to /dev/sda5. It can be done without a restart, but do the mount commands not slowdown/lockup the machine for a while, or is this command instant?

Comment: I would use relatime instead of noatime. It'll update the access time when it is older than the modified time.

Comment: This site even talks about "nodiratime" too which means: Do not  update  directory  inode  access  times  on  this
            filesystem
https://sites.google.com/site/wikirolanddelepper/recommanded-tuning/try-these-first/changing-ext3-default-to-noatime-nodiratime

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Along with the `noatime` option @nos mentioned, you might want to consider the following:

- in nginx, set `access_log off;` -- commenting it out doesn't do anything; you need to actively disable it.
- reduce the number of worker processes. nginx doesn't benefit from more than one worker per CPU.
- `tcp_nodelay on;` will help nginx serve files quicker on "live" connections.
- try playing with `tcp_nopush`. I've found it best to switch it on, but YMMV.
- set `if_modified_since` to `before`; it will allow nginx to send `304 Not Modified` headers rather than re-serving the content.
- play with the [`open_file_cache`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#open_file_cache) settings
- reduce the `send_timeout` so nginx can free-up stale client connections.

As for the rest of your system:

- `hdparam` settings. lots of tutorials to help you online, hdparam tweaks will get the best out of your disks.
- tweak your `socket` [performance settings](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-hisock.html?ca=dgr-lnxw01BoostSocket)
- recompile the kernel with a reduced timer frequency. the default is [1000 Hertz](http://kerneltrap.org/node/5411) which is great for desktop machines providing video but isn't all that good for servers where a value of 100-250 might be more appropriate
- disable services like cups and bluetooth

However, I believe the best performance boost would be putting [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/) in front of your nginx server and using it rather than nginx for serving static files. It will keep "hot" files in memory better than nginx can, so that there's little/no disk use for your most-served content.

The main thing however is to monitor **EVERYTHING** -- don't go with your gut, **know** what your server is doing and where your bottlenecks are.

Comment: Or instead of turning access logs completely off, use buffering: `access_log path combined buffer=16k`

Comment: "tweak your socket" is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Of the 7 million files, how many are frequently accessed? If you're looking at 10KB a piece, you'll only be able to store 500,000 files in the file system cache at most, leaving 1 GB of RAM for the running programs and for file system buffers (which store directory information).

If you can't increase the RAM to hold your frequently accessed files, then you'll need a faster disk setup with lower latency. Moving to a 15K drive will double your disk I/O capacity, but moving to an SSD drive is the best bet for your situation.